# Window is not showing in WPF with DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, devexpress-wpf

I have a WPF application which can't show MainWindow. The same code is working on another project or on another computer.

```
   IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
   kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

   var mainWindow = kernel.Get<MainWindow>();

   if (showMainWindow) mainWindow.Show();

   MainWindow = mainWindow;
```

`mainWindow.Show();` is causing the end of the debugging process.

EventViewer is showing following error:

```
Faulting application name: Esonic.AppCenter.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x5be0180f 
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17134.319, time stamp: 0x5ea0e53d
```

I have tried a reinstall of .NET Framework(4.6.2) and also DevExpress which is in version 15.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was only on specific version of Windows 10 and nowadays is is fixed. Unfortunately I don't know exact version of Windows 10 where it is occcured and what version fixed this isssue.